# Declare argument inside select case structure

Tags: fortran

I write a simple demonstration code to present my question in a quick way. Here's the code, which can not be successfully built.

Main.f90

```
PROGRAM test
IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER    ::   a
    a = 1
    CALL sub(a)

END PROGRAM
```

sub.f90

```
SUBROUTINE sub(a)
IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER    ::   a
    SELECT CASE(a)
        CASE(1)
            INTEGER     ::   b,c
            b = a
            c = a*2
        CASE(2)
            INTEGER     ::   b(4),c(4)
            b(:) = a
            c(:) = a*2
    END SELECT

END SUBROUTINE
```

I tried to compile, but the error shows 'Unexpected data declaration statement' occurs in the subroutine file. Does it mean that I cannot declare argument type inside SELECT CASE structure? The problem is that I want to define the value of a in the main program and pass it into subroutine sub(a). The argument type of b and c should be decided by a, thus I cannot determine in advance. I also want to pass the value of b and c back to the main program, which I don't know how to do that. So how can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to a modern Fortran (2008+) compiler? If so, you can use the `block` construct.

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually trying to make some changes to a program using Fortran 90, so I may want to keep it that way to forbid potential trouble.

Comment: I don't understand you position.  Any standard-conforming Fortran 90 program that does not use deleted features (almost no one used them as they were already declared obsolete) remains standard-conforming Fortran 2015. Bear in mind that Fortran 90 is nearly 3 decades old and doesn't support many modern programming practices. What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as you write it is illegal, as you found out. Now some people have pointed to the 2008 feature of `BLOCK` statements, and if that's what you need, you can try that. But I'd like to learn more about what you want to do with this.

The very fact that you give them the same name suggests to me that you want to treat them the same way later on, which makes things really tricky.

Here are a few alternatives:

1) Use separate variables:

```
INTEGER :: b_scalar, c_scalar, b_array(4), c_array(4)
select case(a)
    case(1)
        b_scalar = a
        c_scalar = 2*b_scalar
    case(2)
        b_array = a
        c_array = 2*b_array
end select
```

2) Use allocatable arrays:

```
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: b, c
select case(a)
    case(1)
        allocate(b(1), c(1))
    case(2)
        allocate(b(4), c(4))
end select
b = a
c = 2 * b
```

Now you have to remember that `b` and `c` are arrays, possibly with length 1. You have to treat them that way.

All of these have advantages and disadvantages. Without knowing why you are doing what you're doing, I don't really know how to best advise you.

As to your second question: The simple way to return them is as an `INTENT(OUT)` dummy argument. Here's a working example:

```
module mod_allocatable
contains
    subroutine my_sub(a, b, c)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: a
        integer, dimension(:), allocatable, intent(out) :: b, c
        if (allocated(b)) deallocate(b)
        if (allocated(c)) deallocate(c)
        select case(a)
            case(1)
                allocate(b(1), c(1))
            case(2)
                allocate(b(4), c(4))
        end select
        b = a
        c = 2 * b
      end subroutine my_sub
end module mod_allocatable

program test_alloc
    use mod_allocatable
    implicit none
    integer :: a
    integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: b, c
    a = 1
    call my_sub(a, b, c)
    print *, "b is ", b
    print *, "c is ", c
end program test_alloc
```

Comment: As `b` and `c` are `intent(out)` the test of allocation status is redundant: at that point they are certainly not allocated.

Comment: Thanks, @francescalus. I usually try to be prepared anyhow. If that is indeed redundant, I expect the compiler to remove that.

Comment: @chw21 Thank you very much for the answer. I want to keep the name of b and c in both scalar and vector occasions because I want to use them as overloading input of another interface. The overloading procedure will choose subroutine automatically by identifying the input type. In this way I can keep variable number and subroutine number minimum.

Answer (score 3):

So you you are actually asking how to return scalar or array from some subroutine, not how to declare construct-local variables. In that case consider using two separate subroutines. One version for scalars and one for arrays. You can overload them as a generic procedure under one name if you want.

Also think about `ELEMENTAL`, but if you use scalar `a` it won't work with the arrays.

---

If you still want to know how to declare local variables:

Variables can only be declared at the beginning of the procedure or at the beginning of a block. That is a Fortran 2008 feature supported in recent versions of the most common compilers (from PC compilers at least GNU and Intel).

```
SELECT CASE(a)
    CASE(1)
        BLOCK
          INTEGER     ::   b,c
          b = a
          c = a*2
        END BLOCK
```

Comment: Interesting. But do these declared variables survive the end of the `BLOCK` statement? I suspect not.

Comment: @chw21 Of course not. And if the syntax the OP was suggesting existed they wouldn't survive either.

Comment: b and c are saved if b= and c=, or if the SAVE is attached.

Comment: That is different, with save they retain value but are still valid only within the block.

Comment: @VladimirF Which makes this troublesome, as the OP also posted that he wants to hand `b` and `c` back to the calling routine.

Comment: In that case he should make two subroutines. A typical example where someone asks for some detail, but his real problem is different.

Comment: You are right, I should make two different subroutines. The reason I didn't do this in the first place is that the two subroutines are mostly the same, and it may complicate my program in a unnecessary way. But it seems this is the best choice for me now

Answer (score 0):

This is not overly elegant...

```
  SUBROUTINE sub(a)
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER,               INTENT(IN)   ::   a
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE  :: b, c

    SELECT CASE(a)
        CASE(1)
            IF(ALLOCATED(B)) THEN
              IF(UBOUND(B)) .NE. 1) THEN
                DEALLOCATE(B)
                ALLOCATE(B(1))
              ENDIF
            ELSE
              ALLOCATE(B(1))
            ENDIF

            IF(ALLOCATED(C)) THEN
              IF(UBOUND(C)) .NE. 1) THEN
                DEALLOCATE(c)
                ALLOCATE(C(1))
              ENDIF
            ELSE
              ALLOCATE(C(1))
            ENDIF

            b = a
            c = a*2
        CASE(2)
            IF(ALLOCATED(B)) THEN
              IF(UBOUND(B)) .NE. 4) THEN
                DEALLOCATE(B)
                ALLOCATE(B(4))
              ENDIF
            ELSE
              ALLOCATE(B(4))
            ENDIF

            IF(ALLOCATED(C)) THEN
              IF(UBOUND(C)) .NE. 4) THEN
                DEALLOCATE(C)
                ALLOCATE(C(4))
              ENDIF
            ELSE
              ALLOCATE(C(4))
            ENDIF

            b(:) = a
            c(:) = a*2
        CASE(DEFAULT)
            WRITE(*,*)'how did we get here?... a=',a
    END SELECT

END SUBROUTINE Sub
```

Comment: Yeah - If fixed it to read b and c (from a and b).
And chw21 poked in a very similar approach while I was poking at the keys.

Comment: Actually in chw21's answer bring up an interesting point. The INTENT may need to be INOUT for B and C. I know UBOUND does not know what the bounds of B are without INTENT having IN or INOUT. It is a bit counter intuitive when you know it is basically OUT, but you need the IN for some of the stuff that is not apparent.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your final comment: `b` and `c` aren't dummy arguments (so cannot have intent).  That also means that (as they aren't `save`d) we know at the start of the case construct that `b` and `c` aren't allocated: giving a chunk of conditional parts which will never be executed.

Comment: I suppose b and c are meant to be dummy arguments and are just left out of the argument list by mistake.